# Django error traceback not showing the real error

Tags: python, django, traceback

In a Django view method, I have some code like this:

```
x = my_dict['foo']
```

'foo' is not in my_dict, so I'm getting an error traceback screen, as I should.

However, the error screen claims the error is deep in some internal django module, rather than in my code.  Here is the traceback information:

```
Traceback:
File "/usr/lib/python2.3/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  99.                     response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

Exception Type: KeyError at /app/login/
Exception Value: 'foo'
```

Why isn't it showing me the line of code from my view method?

Comment: That function -- eventually -- called your function.  It's in the traceback.  But it's not first.

Comment: My function isn't mentioned in the traceback at all, first last or middle.  Honest.

Comment: Your view functions can be hard to spot in a complex traceback.  Honest. It's possible that the unhandled exception manifested itself somewhere else in Django.  Remember.  Your view function is only a tiny piece of request-response processing in Django.  There's url matching, middleware, and template repines rendering.  If you want a real answer, not comments, you'll have to post the actual traceback message in all it's glory.  Not just one line.

Comment: I edited the base note to include all the traceback info.  That's all there was (omitting the few lines of code above and below the offending line that it provides for context.)

Comment: Are you getting this traceback from the Django 500 view?

Comment: Yes, it's displaying the debugging error screen instead of a 500 view because I have DEBUG=True in the settings file.

Comment: Which version of Django?   My error traceback HTML pages seem to be far more complex than a single line of traceback.  My HTML page has **Traceback** with a link  "Switch to copy-and-paste view".  This contains the full traceback.

Comment: It's a somewhat older version of Django, 1.1 I believe.  And I have gotten a more complete traceback on other errors, but for this error I'm only getting the one line.

Comment: 1.1 has very complete traceback.  I'm quite surprised there is not a "Switch to copy-and-paste view" link that will reveal a much bigger traceback.

Comment: There is a "switch to copy-and-paste view" link, but the traceback section has only the one line.

Comment: At this point -- assuming you really did click the "switch to copy-and-paste view " link -- I can only assume  your browser is broken.  Do a view source on the page to see if the traceback is on the page but not displayed.

Answer (score 2):

I believe Django is considering the error to be that the view hasn't returned a valid HTTPResponse and conveying that rather than the reason for the view not conveying the response. I believe this is by design.

To get to the specific error look at your web-server's error log.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me as django showed me complete error trace only once then after that error trace was not complete.

Try turning `DEBUG = True` this will show you the complete error log.